# draw a spot in the bitmap image

Tags: android

Anybody please help me with some hints to draw a spot(small filled circle) on a bitmap image.

Comment: hi asifkt can u tell me how u have drawn the circle without using canvas???????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [create a new Canvas on your Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29), create a new [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) object and call [`drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) on your canvas using the defined paint variable.

Comment: can i draw the circle without using canvas??